# Cannot find module 'grunt-lib-phantomjs' in 'grunt-contrib-qunit'

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I have installed `phantomjs 1.9.7` wgetting the zip and then moving it to PATH in ubuntu virtualbox.

On nodejs project, firing `npm install -no-bin-links` goes fine, but `grunt test` fails with following error,

```
root@ubuntu1204:/home/prayagupd/vboxshared/onlywallet# grunt test
Loading "qunit.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'grunt-lib-phantomjs'
Warning: Task "qunit" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

While checking `grunt-contrib-quint`, there's no `grunt-lib-phantomjs` inside `node_modules`,

```
root@ubuntu1204:/home/prayagupd/vboxshared/onlywallet# ls -l node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/
total 36
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  1076 Oct 14  2012 LICENSE-MIT
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 10267 May 27 14:11 package.json
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Jun 22  2013 phantomjs
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  8660 Jan 17 05:25 README.md
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Oct  1  2013 tasks


root@ubuntu1204:/home/prayagupd/vboxshared/onlywallet# ls -l node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/phantomjs/
total 4
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1574 Jun 22  2013 bridge.js
```

However, in my local machine I've got `grunt-lib-phantomjs` after `npm install`

```
$ ls -l node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 prayagupd prayagupd 4096 May 27 22:00 grunt-lib-phantomjs
```

My `package.json` is,

```
 1 {                                                                                                                                                 
  2   "name": "zazzercode",                                                                             
  3   "version": "0.13.1",                                                                              
  4   "devDependencies": {                                                                              
  5     "grunt": "~0.4.1",                                                                              
  6     "intern": "~1.2.1",                                                                             
  7     "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",                                                               
  8     "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.4.0",                                                                
  9     "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",                                                                
 10     "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.3.2",                                                               
 11     "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",                                                               
 12     "grunt-closure-compiler": "0.0.18"                                                              
 13   },                                                                                                
 14   "repository": {                                                                                   
 15     "type": "git",                                                                                  
 16     "url": "https://github.com/iPrayag/onlywallet"                                 
 17   }                                                                                                 
 18 }
```

There are number of issues fired at github, but none worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install -g grunt-contrib-qunit` before `npm install --no-bin-links` seems to have worked.

Comment: Is there any explanation why?

Comment: `npm install -g` doesn't work if you don't have `sudo` access